# c++ Clear stringstream using one-liner m.swap(std::stringstream());?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, stringstream

I have been using the following code to clear `std::stringstream`:

```
m.swap(std::stringstream());
```

Code probably taken from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23266418/2672807). Recently I compiled my code in Visual Studio 2013 and I received the following warning:

```
warning C4239: nonstandard extension used : 'argument' : conversion from 'std::basic_stringstream<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' to 'std::basic_stringstream<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &'
1>          A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue
```

I did not receive any warning in earlier versions of Visual Studio using /W4. I recall I had trouble reliably clearing stringstreams in earlier versions which is why I ended up using that code in the first place.

So is it portable to clear a stringstream that way, and if not could you explain why not? Also is there a portable way to clear a stringstream? Thanks

Edit: Here is the code that was requested. Compile it using `/W4` to see the warning.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::stringstream m;
    m.swap(std::stringstream());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it dude, could you post some code?

Comment: @Manu343726 relax dude.

Comment: In my VS++2013 compiles fine.

Comment: @Manu343726 Because no other compiler has nonstandard extensions. Oh wait, they all do. (Admittedly, this particular extension does suck)

Comment: I did a console application in VS2013, I run the piece of code you posted with no optimizations, and I can't reproduce. It compiles fine with no warnings.

Comment: @40two Using what /W level?

Comment: @40two I'm using warning level `/W4`. I will update my post with that information.

Comment: Sorry guys I confirm with `/W4` I can reproduce. I had `/W3` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `std::swap` function takes two **non-const** parameters to swap. This is because both parameters are changed when the function is called. Similarly, the `std::stringstream::swap(...)` function, takes a single **non-const** parameter to swap with.

For example:

```
std::vector<int> vec1, vec2;
std::swap(vec1, vec2);
```

In the above sample, both `vec1` and `vec2` are altered. When you try to do this...

```
m.swap(std::stringstream());
```

... you're trying to assign the contents of the temporary `std::stringstream()` with the contents of `m`, which to a compiler looks like a bug, even if your intention was simply to clear the contents of `m`.

To remove the warning, simply declare a temporary `std::stringstream` before performing the swap. Like this:

```
std::stringstream temp;
m.swap(temp);
```

Comment: Alternately, make the temporary first. `std::stringstream().swap(m);`

Comment: @BillyONeal - Indeed you could also do that!

Comment: Had somewhat a similar issue... see the comments about the `lvalue` template  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23714445/passing-temporary-istringstream-object-to-istream-iteratorstring/23714506#23714506

Comment: Basically you are bounding a temporary to a non-const lvalue reference, which is not possible. You have to create a reference to the temporary, `template<typename T> T& ref_from_temp(T&& x) {return x;}` using move semantics in C++11, then replace `m.swap(stringstream());` by `m.swap(ref_from_temp(stringstream()));`

Comment: @vsoftco Thanks for the suggestion. I decided to go with Billy's one-liner since even though it's not strictly C++03 compatible it works with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @vsoftco: No, you are not binding a temporary to a non-const lvalue reference there. The only thing bound to a non-const lvalue reference is `m`, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: @user: It is valid C++03.

Comment: @BillyONeal, in `m.swap(std::stringstream());`, don't you try to invoke `swap` with a temp reference? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/swap/ At least that's my understanding.

Comment: @vsoftco: Yes, that would be bad. That's why I said `std::stringstream().swap(m)`. The temporary becomes `this` and `m` is bound to the non-const lvalue reference. Swap doesn't care who is the left hand side and who is the right hand side.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the signature of `std::stringstream::swap()`:

```
void swap( basic_stringstream& other );
```

As you can see, `swap()` takes an lvalue-reference to its argument. An rvalue or temporary cannot bind to an lvalue-reference as your compiler is correctly telling you. Some compilers support non-standard extensions that allow you to do this, but I would advise that you stay within the bounds of the standard, it's much safer.

However, while you may not be able to bind the temporary to the lvalue-reference, you can *transform* the temporary into an lvalue using this `std::skipws` trick:

```
m.swap(static_cast<std::stringstream&>(stringstream{} >> std::skipws));
```

or even

```
std::stringstream{}.swap(m):
```

In the first example, the function `operator>>()` returns a reference to the stream, which is safe to use with `swap()` because the reference that holds the argument is destroyed at the end of the function.

Comment: @vsoftco How exactly doesn't it work? Are you receiving an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: Yes, `error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'std::__1::basic_istream<char>'`

Comment: this is the code `#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stringstream m;
    m.swap(stringstream{} >> skipws);
}
`

Comment: It works if you use a move function to add a reference, as you mentioned before on my problem with stringstreams.

Comment: @vsoftco Oh I see. You have to cast it to a `std::stringstream&` to get that to work.

Comment: @vsoftco Yup, that's another solution. Thanks for reminding me. `:D`

Comment: Although I am getting a g++ 4.8 error that `error: 'std::stringstream' has no member named 'swap'`, even though it looks like `stringstream` has a swap member, I am now really confused about `g++` implementation of the standard. It should work according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/swap/ So basically I cannot swap 2 stringstreams, like `m.swap(n)`, where `stringstream m,n;`

Comment: @vsoftco Turns out g++ doesn't support `std::stringstream::swap()`. I was trying this code on clang where it happily compiled. Then again, clang is known for being more up-to-date than g++. `swap()` is a newly-added C++11 function.

Comment: Well this is strange, just tried it with `g++4.9` and still doesn't work, although they claim that `g++4.9` is fully C++11 ready... `clang++` indeed works.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Can you tell me why you need the `static_cast`? As I understood before, the `>>` operator returns a reference, why then do you need to cast it again? Thanks!

Comment: @vsoftco Because `operator>>()` returns *`std::istream&`* not `std::stringstream&`. We need to downcast it to a reference to the derived class.

Answer (score 1):

That use of `swap` is not allowed by the Standard.  The declaration is

```
template <typename CharT, typename Traits, typename Allocator>
void std::basic_stringstream<CharT, Traits, Allocator>::swap(
    basic_stringstream& other);
```

which implies that both `stringstream` objects will be modified.  But the expression `std::stringstream()` is an rvalue (specifically, a temporary), and C++ does not allow binding non-const lvalue references to temporaries, since modifying a temporary is not often the real intent.

The easy solution is:

```
m = std::stringstream();
```

But if you need to support compilers without C++11 support, neither will work, since in the C++03 Standard, `stringstream` has no `swap` function and no public `operator=`.  In that case, you would need to go with:

```
m.clear();
m.str(std::string());
```

Comment: How do you explain the fact that the example posted compiles?

Comment: The problem with .str() is apparently it didn't always work for me to clear the stream and I don't remember why.

Comment: `m.clear()` might also be necessary to do a full reset.  And maybe other things.  This is difficult using only C++03 functions.

Comment: Ok thanks for the extra information, I appreciate it. I decided to go with `std::stringstream().swap(m);` since even though it's not C++03 it works in Visual Studio 2010 and 2013. I would really like better portability but I don't want to run the risk of introducing a bug  if more than clear() and str(std::string()) is required.